# rbenv install 2.4.0 fails in Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos-sierra, rbenv

```
> rbenv install 2.4.0 ruby-build: use openssl from homebrew Downloading
> ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2...
> -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.0.tar.bz2 Installing ruby-2.4.0... ruby-build: use readline from homebrew
> 
> BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.12.6 using ruby-build 20170726)
> 
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at
> /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759
> Results logged to
> /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759.log
> 
> Last 10 log lines:   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tar   Expected
> in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> 
> dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat   Referenced from:
> /usr/local/bin/tar   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
> 
> /usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 344: 21953 Abort trap: 6           tar
> $tar_args "$package_filename"
> /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759/ruby-2.4.0
> /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759
> ~/Documents/Github /usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 563: ./configure:
> No such file or directory
```

---

contents for /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build‌​.20170728015414.2175‌​9.log

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
>   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/tar   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/bin/tar   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> /usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 344: 21953 Abort trap: 6           tar
>   $tar_args "$package_filename"
>   /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759/ruby-2.4.0
>   /var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759
>   ~/Documents/Github /usr/local/bin/ruby-build: line 563: ./configure:
>   No such file or directory

Comment: Can you post the contents of the log file (`/var/folders/9_/xjrq9lv11hl_82pmlzqh3h0m0000gn/T/ruby-build.20170728015414.21759.log`), please?

Comment: I added the contents of that file above. Thanks for taking a look @LucasCosta

Comment: This is very weird... Looks like you are in trouble with tar. Could you try to remove and install it again, please?

Comment: Btw, in my computer, when I type `tar --version` I got `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`.

Comment: finally it worked. I removed that tar and use the native tar from macos like you said @LucasCosta and it worked. Looks like gnu-tar could not keep up with newer release of macOS. but thanks much. You save my rbenv! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brew uninstall tar 

rbenv install ruby 2.4.0
```

Now it works, so looks like gnu-tar didn't play well with Mac OS 10.12.16 at the moment, must fall back to native macos tar

thanks @LucasCosta

Comment: This didn't work for me. First, I got the same build error for ruby 2.4.2 and 2.4.0: linking shared-object zlib.bundle
*** Following extensions failed to configure:
../.././ext/gdbm/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure gdbm. It will not be installed. Then later, I see: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat. Second, I think you meant: "rbenv install 2.4.0" else with "ruby," rbenv command is unexpected.

Comment: The whole error: linking shared-object zlib.bundle
*** Following extensions failed to configure:  
../.././ext/gdbm/extconf.rb:0: Failed to configure gdbm. It will not be installed.
*** Fix the problems, then remove these directories and try again if you want.  
linking ruby  
Generating RDoc documentation  
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat  
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/pn/8dks58m57llbpngp0fvcdbf00000gn/T/ruby-build.20171001101324.69785/ruby-2.4.2/./ruby  
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Comment: @BoiseBaked Did you get to resolve this? I had a similar issue, turned out that it was from installing new Xcode without installing new developer tools. After running `xcode-select --install`, I was then able to use rbenv to install rubies. Ref: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3744 (see comments for success from rvm and rbenv users)

Comment: Yes @nicksuch, I found the issues asked and answered here: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1133. For me, yes, it was the xcode ver9 thing and running xcode-select as you described worked. After I was able to install ruby 2.4.2 using "rbenv install 2.4.2". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
xcode-select --install
```

fixes the similar ruby 2.4.2 installation problem on MacOS Sierra, happening when XCode 9 is installed without XCode Developer Tools.